# JPA - Fetch child object from REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I'm writing a Spring Boot (with JPA) REST application where one of the entities that compose my model is owned by a different/external service, which can be fetch using a REST api.

```
@Entity
public class ManagedEntity {
  @Id
  private UUID id;      
  private ExternalEntity external; // I can be fetch from a REST api
}
```

I'd like to know how should I map my entity in order to have my JPA implementation to load it from the REST api, if possible.

Or, what would be the best way to model my entity/application in order to have a rich model?

Comment: That's not possible. JPA reads data from a relational database, and relies on its transactional capabilities. You can't join a table row with a non-transactional REST service. You need to handle that at a higher level than the database persistence layer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do at data-access-layer. You can load the data in the business logic. Change your `@Entity` class adding

```
@Transient 
private ExternalEntity external;
```

Fetch the data from the DB first and then try to make a service call to populate `ExternalEntity`

Answer (score 0):

You could mark entire ExternalEntity with @Transient and initialize it in a service logic.

But the best way in returning data is to return view objects instead of JPA domain objects

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked the question with a Spring tag and since you seem to be looking for the easy-done-for-you suggestion, why not use [Spring-Data-REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/)? From the front page ...

> > Spring Data REST
> >
> > Spring Data REST is part of the umbrella Spring Data project and makes it easy to build hypermedia-driven REST web services on top of Spring Data repositories.